Embarrassed student goes on a killing spree and makes a kill list with hero's name on it
In this film, a fellow student is embarrassed by an 'incident' in which he was bullied by his college mates and begins a killing spree. He also keeps a list of people he has to kill, striking out names one by one after completing the killing. 
The hero of the film feels strange about the list of the people being killed which makes him feels that he is next.
Meanwhile the cops question the alumni one by one because they feel that one among the alumni is the killer. They even question the killer due to his presence at the killings, but dismiss him off since they feel that he is good for nothing. 
The hero discusses with his girlfriend that he feels that he is next on the list. His girlfriend suggests that he recalls any incident of harassing any fellow student. Hero admits that he has been with a gang in an 'incident' in which they harassed a fellow student, but the student is so innocent, that he can't be the killer. (But actually this fellow student is the killer). The girlfriend suggests that the hero apologises to this fellow student and stay at peace.
The hero calls up the fellow student and apologises to him of their harassment. The fellow student (killer) is so... moved to tears (No one has ever respected him so far in his life. No one has ever said sorry to him so far in his life). But he answers the hero's call with integrity, saying he forgot about this 'incident' long ago and he doesn't mind. 
Hanging up the call, the killer strikes out hero's name from his list and begins targeting the next person on the list. The hero and the killer meet each other in the next alumni get together and smile at each other.
The killer continues his killing spree.

Seeing how accurately you remember the actual plot, is there anything else you remember and can tell us? Any descriptions of the characters or settings? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? You also might want to specify your question title a bit, it's already pretty clear from the tags that you're looking for a movie whose title you can't remember.

You might be remembering this scene from "Billy Madison": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68sRqrZZ6wQ

The question title is now complete and meaningful. Thanks buddy for editing it. The film is from US as far as i can remember. The killer character looks so naive, that the cops interogating him feel that, he is unfit to do criminal activities. Most of the settings go like this, an alumni get together party and the hero's residence.

Some of your description reminds me of "Murder by Numbers" with Micheal Pitt: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0264935/

Thank you buddies for the response. Yes, the killer looks innocent and harmless like Micheal Pitt in "Murder by Numbers". But still, I am having trouble remembering the title.  Both "Billy Madison" and "Murder by Numbers" are good movies to watch, but i like this unknown title better. This for the fragile demeanor of the killer and the closeness to death of the protagonist. All these inter-dwindled unsolvable plot, just solves by the act of kindness of the protagonist.  Hope some one who has seen this film reads this question.

Another similar plot can be found in Valentine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentine_(film)

Where did you see it and which decade would you say it was from?

@Prabhuram Do you happen to remember how he kills the people from his list?

@WillFeldman That's what I thought of too. I checked IMDB's connection page for Billy Madison, but there was nothing mentioned about that scene. If Billy Madison actually did spoof this movie, we know that it was earlier than 1995.

The movie seems similar to Heart of America, by Uwe Boll - number 7 on this list
This movie includes a student, Daniel Lynn, who shoots three people who had previously bullied him. Heart of America is also similar as there is a bully who realises that what he has done is wrong, and there is also theme of a list of bullies to be killed, like in the description.
Although the films are similar, I am not sure about this answer (there are some useful comments below it).

Please expand on your answer to explain how this film is similar to the one described in the question.

Oh - is it not? Sorry, seemed similar

I'm not saying that it's wrong, I'm asking you to use your answer to explain the similarities. I've not seen it, so I have no clue either way. Link-only answers are discouraged so I'm inviting you to improve your answer :D

I have to say this seems nothing like the question. I was happy to see an answer because I've seen the film the guy wants just stuck on the title too.

It's good you are having a go thou. Although the question is more about a serial killer than a spree killer.

@YetisasquatchAlienbeliever Are there any details you remember that aren't in the question, then? Approximate year, other scenes\plot details, possible actors etc.?

Oh yes, sorry. When the Guy's girlfriend is speaking to him about maybe contacting the bullied bloke they are in an apartment and in this scene or the following one he looks out the window. Also when he next sees the killer at that meeting described it is from across the room, the killer is standing near the far wall, I believe the MC walks in and across to the far left past the crowd the killer is near the wall. I don't want to confuse the issue with who I think the detective is as so far I have been wrong. I should have added this info earlier.

Sorry about the incorrect answer - I haven't seen either film. The theme of the bullied student making a list of bullies to kill seemed really similar. Should I delete the answer?

Also in a flash back scene IIRC the bulling incident takes place in a hallway and the MC is not as involved as the others. Actually I think he just may have been there friends but did not partake.
